# Jquery mobile scroll position

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

noob-ish question here, I'm working on a project using the last jQ Mobile (1.4.2) I have a page which is longer than the height of the device and I need to know the position of the currently displayed things ( e.g. 0 if I am at the top , height-deviceheight if I am at the bottom of the page).

Any Hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a scroll event listener such as [`scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and with that you can use [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to find out the position of the scroll, like so:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('p').text("Scrolled " + $(window).scrollTop() + " pixels");
});
```

## JsFiddle

Comment: Thank you @urbz I adapted your idea to my problem and it works like a charm :) .